# Getting code to run synchronously that resides inside a function called via an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a dropdown notification window that I show when I run certain AJAX functions, let's simplify it as:

```
function notifyComplete(type, alert_el, response) {

    var msg = response.output;
    var result = response.result;

    // Update msg in alert box
    alert_el.text(msg);

    if (result == 'success') {
        alert_el.addClass('alert-success');
    } else {
        alert_el.addClass('alert-danger');
    }

    // Slide in alert box
    alert_el.addClass('visible');

}
```

...and I might call it like so:

```
var alert_el = $('#top_notify').find('.alert');

// Remove any additional classes added by a possible previous run
alert_el.removeClass('visible alert-success alert-info alert-danger alert-warning');

getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, 'POST', 'json')

    .done(function(response) {
        notifyComplete(notify_type, alert_el, response);
    });
```

..and here is the `getAjaxData` function if of interest:

```
function getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, action, type) {

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: action,
        url: loadUrl,
        data: dataObject,
        dataType: type
    });

}
```

Now what I am trying to do is find a way I can place this code:

```
var alert_el = $('#top_notify').find('.alert');

// Remove any additional classes added by a possible previous run
alert_el.removeClass('visible alert-success alert-info alert-danger alert-warning');
```

...somewhere where I don't have to repeat it every time I want to use the `notifyComplete` function.

Obviously if `notifyComplete` is going to be always called within an AJAX block then I can't put it inside the function itself as then you wouldn't be able to get the notify box to slide down more than once without a page reload.

Also, I can't do it *afterwards* as the slide down notify window duration is handled by CSS and hence JS doesn't know when it's complete.

I had built a current working example on **CodePen** [here](http://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/xRXbXy) but it seems it's broken because of an issue with crossorigin.me

Comment: Are you trying to call `var alert_el = $('#top_notify').find('.alert');` before each `getAjaxData` call?

Comment: @guest271314 Well, not really, I can easily move that somewhere global, the main problem is the next line that removes the classes at the start of each call.

Comment: What is the issue with next line? Are you trying to call `alert_el.removeClass('visible alert-success alert-info alert-danger alert-warning')` before each `$.ajax()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to call

```
var alert_el = $('#top_notify').find('.alert');

// Remove any additional classes added by a possible previous run
alert_el.removeClass('visible alert-success alert-info alert-danger alert-warning');
```

before each `$.ajax()` call, you can include the lines within `$.ajax()` `beforeSend` function within `getAjaxData`

```
function getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, action, type) {

    return jQuery.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(jqxhr, settings) {
                      var alert_el = $('#top_notify').find('.alert');
                      // Remove any additional classes added by a possible previous run
                      alert_el
                     .removeClass('visible alert-success alert-info alert-danger alert-warning');
        },
        type: action,
        url: loadUrl,
        data: dataObject,
        dataType: type
    });

}
```

If you are trying to call the two lines after `$.ajax()` call, though before `notifyComplete` you can pass an array of function to `.done()`

```
getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, 'POST', 'json')
.done([
  function(response) {
    var alert_el = $('#top_notify').find('.alert');
    // Remove any additional classes added by a possible previous run
    alert_el
    .removeClass('visible alert-success alert-info alert-danger alert-warning');
  }
  , function(response) {
      notifyComplete(notify_type, alert_el, response);
  }
 ]);
```

---

> if I could pass it a function name as a callback rather than use an
>   anonymous function and thus have to resort to using `if/else` inside,
>   but obviously also need a way of including parameters with the
>   callback.

You can use `Function.prototype.bind()` to pass additional parameters to a named function set as value of `beforeSend` option of `$.ajax()`. Include logic to check if the additional object or value is the passed object or jQuery `jqxhr` object that is the default first parameter of `beforeSend`.

```
  function handleBeforeSend(args, jqxhr, settings) {
    console.log(args, jqxhr, settings);
    if (args.hasOwnProperty("additionalSettings")) {
      // do stuff with `args.additionalSettings`
    }
  }

  $.ajax({
    url:"/path/to/server/",
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: handleBeforeSend.bind(null, {additionalSettings:[0,1,2]})
  });
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dackdrek/

---

Implemented within current `javascript`

```
$().ready(function() {

  function handleBeforeSend(bool, jqxhr, settings) {
    console.log(bool, jqxhr, settings);
    if (bool === true) {
      var alert_el = $('#top_notify').find('.alert');
      // Remove any additional classes added by a possible previous run
      alert_el.removeClass('visible alert-success alert-info alert-danger alert-warning');
    }
  }

  function notifyComplete(type, alert_el, response) {

    var msg = response.output;
    var result = response.result;

    // Update msg in alert box
    alert_el.text(msg);

    if (result == 'success') {
      alert_el.addClass('alert-success');
    } else {
      alert_el.addClass('alert-danger');
    }

    // Slide in alert box
    alert_el.addClass('visible');

  }

  function getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, action, type, beforeSend, bool) {

    return jQuery.ajax({
      type: action,
      url: loadUrl,
      data: dataObject,
      dataType: type,
      beforeSend: beforeSend.bind(null, bool)
    });

  }
  // pass `true` to `handleBeforeSend`
  getAjaxData("/echo/json/", {
      json: JSON.stringify({
          "output": "123",
          "result": "success"
        })
      }, "POST", "json", handleBeforeSend, true)
    .then(function(response) {
      notifyComplete(null, $('#top_notify'), response)
    });
  setTimeout(function() {
  // pass `false` to `handleBeforeSend`
  getAjaxData("/echo/json/", {
      json: JSON.stringify({
          "output": "123",
          "result": "success"
        })
      }, "POST", "json", handleBeforeSend, false)
    .then(function(response) {
      notifyComplete(null, $('#top_notify'), response)
    })
   }, 5000)
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dackdrek/4/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That `getAjaxData` function us used by a whole stack of things (whenever I need to do an ajax call) so adding that `beforeSend` to it wouldn't work, unless I could add another optional parameter to the function where I could pass in a callback function to be called within `beforeSend`.

Comment: @Brett Yes, you can call a function within `beforeSend`, within `if..else` statements, if necessary.

Comment: No, I mean I see `beforeSend` accepts a function, I was asking if I could pass it a function name as a callback rather than use an anonymous function and thus have to resort to using `if/else` inside, but obviously also need a way of including parameters with the callback.

Comment: Yes, you can pass a function reference as value to `beforeSend` option of `$.ajax()`; use `Function.prototype.bind()` to pass parameters to the function when called. Note, the default parameters are `jqXHR` object and `$.ajax()` `settings` object.

Comment: Ok, would you be able to update your answer with an example so as the solution is not buried in the comments?

Comment: Sorry, I meant being able to pass a function name as a parameter to the `getAjaxData` function, so then I would be able to pass the function `notifyComplete` to it so it would run that, but I obviously would also need to be able to pass the parameters needed for it in `type, alert_el, response`.

Comment: @Brett Yes, that is what pattern at `javascript` at updated Answer achieves. You can pass the function name,  e.g., `handleBeforeSend` and any additional parameters, for example `{additionalSettings:[0,1,2]}` to the function.

Comment: I want to be able to call it like this: `getAjaxData(loadUrl, dataObject, 'POST', 'json', notifyComplete)` as in, be able to pass in the function reference as the last optional parameter. From what I can make out from your example I would have to call it like this: `getAjaxData(notifyComplete, {additionalSettings:[4,5,6]})` where `additionalSettings` is an array of parameters for the `notifyComplete` function? What about the first four parameters for `getAjaxData` as in: `loadUrl, dataObject, 'POST', 'json'` ?

Comment: @Brett Define `handleBeforeSend` outside of `getAjaxData`. If the only procedure that you want to perform is to call `var alert_el = $('#top_notify').find('.alert');
alert_el.removeClass('visible alert-success alert-info alert-danger alert-warning')` before `$.ajax()` call, you can adjust `if` condition to a `Boolean`, you can include the two lines within `handleBeforeSend` at `if` statement. When you want to call `handleBeforeSend` pass `true` to `getAjaxData` https://jsfiddle.net/dackdrek/3/

Comment: All I'm trying to do is if I am going to go the route of using `beforeSend` option within the common `getAjaxData` function then I want to do it in a clean manner in where I can pass the name of a callback function as another parameter to `getAjaxData` and then other code that uses `getAjaxData` that _doesn't_ need to pass a callback function then doesn't need to include that parameter. I checked the fiddle again but it contains a hardcoded function name of `handleBeforeSend`, a function that would only be relevant to this one call and nothing else,hence my need to pass the function name.

Comment: @Brett You can use the same pattern. Include a parameter at `getAjaxData`, pass the function reference https://jsfiddle.net/dackdrek/4/

Comment: Oh ok got it. Would you be able to update the answer with those changes? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

1. You can use `setTimeout` in the `notifyComplete` function, place it at the end and give it a reasonable amount of time so the notification alert disappears automatically after it appears
2. > Also, I can't do it afterwards as the slide down notify window duration is handled by CSS and hence JS doesn't know when it's complete.

   That is not correct, you can use the [`trantisitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) or [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) events to check when a CSS effect has finished. If you are using something like bootstrap, you can use transitionend in the alert element.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of those events, they will probably be useful - I will give them a go.

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately it removes the classes after the _first_ transition ends and not the _complete_ transition. So for my `transition` which you can see on the CodePen being: `transition: 0.8s 0s, opacity 1s 3.8s;` it removes the classes once it has finished sliding down rather when the opacity has made it vanish.

Comment: That is because the event handler is fired with ALL the transitions affecting that element. Use some checks with the property of the transition event (`event.propertyName === 'opacity'` should work)

Comment: Ahh ok, makes sense. I will try your suggestion and report back.

Comment: If your set of transitions get complex, I suggest to toggle css classes with states to know when you are done. I did something like that [here](http://codepen.io/YerkoPalma/pen/OXPYMK) hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that was interesting :) But I tried checking the `propertyName` as you suggested but it outputs `background-color`.

Comment: I console logged the whole event and it has a `elapsedTime` of `0.8` so that must be referencing the first transition, doesn't seem to be going through to the `opacity` transition?