# Jquery update function when needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

A BUTTON calls new posts everytime it's clicked.
Function calls the posts through AJAX.
Each post has the same calculator on it.

POST EXAMPLE:

```
<div class="post">
 <div class="a">1</div>
 <div class="b">8</div>
 <div class="sum">x</div>
 <div class="count">Count</div>
<div>
```

I have a function, which of course doesn't work if it's called before the post appeared. In another words, if POST is added, this function will not work if it's not called AFTER the post is added. This is because of naturallity of javascript.
FUNCTION EXAMPLE:

function loadCounter(){
    $(".count").click(function(){
     $(this).parent().find(".sum").html(parseInt($(this).parent().find(".a").html())+parseInt($(this).parent().find(".b").html()))

```
})
```

}

Now if the function would be called each time AJAX is called - browser would use it the same few times. It's something like:

```
$(".count").click(function(){
 $(this).parent().find(".sum").html(parseInt($(this).parent().find(".a").html())+parseInt($(this).parent().find(".b").html()))
 $(this).parent().find(".sum").html(parseInt($(this).parent().find(".a").html())+parseInt($(this).parent().find(".b").html()))
 $(this).parent().find(".sum").html(parseInt($(this).parent().find(".a").html())+parseInt($(this).parent().find(".b").html()))

})
```

And the result on each post would be not 1+8=9, but 18 or 27, etc.

I can't come up with the solution, maybe someone could help me with this please?

Comment: What is preventing you from calling this function when ajax completes? you need to show us some code to give context to this problem as well as improve the problem description. Take some time to thoroughly read [ask] and [mcve] then edit the question with applicable udates

Comment: why are you not calling the function from the ajax success?

Comment: Mate, the codes will not help at this point. I just can explain it better. AJAX adds new html posts, which has calculators inside in each of it. Calculator function doesn't work, unless it's called after the post appear. If the function is called multiple times, calculator, will give results from the same multiple functions. I need that function to run only once. So it should be killed and it should start again, each time new post is added with AJAX. But I am afraid it's impossible, that's why I am asking your help.

Comment: Samples of the ajax and the function code would clearly help us help you. You have not had enough time to thoroughly read and comprehend the above links

Comment: @charlietfl I can't call it after AJAX success because my ajax can keep returning new posts, and so it would call the same function again. The same multiple functions does the same multiple actions. For example my function would be add 2+2 number from html input, so if the function is called twice it would output 8.

Comment: Without code this question remains unclear, and should be closed.

Comment: @trincot Whatever, I will write the code for it, one minute.

Comment: I'm sure it can...but we can not deal in hypotheticals here. READ THE LINKS

Comment: @trincot I've added some codes and a better explanation. I hope you'll understand it now. Thanks for everyone's help anyway

Comment: Are you trying to call anonymous function at `.click()` handler before each `$.post()` call? Are you currently attaching `.click()` event at each `$.post()`?

Comment: @guest271314 Well I am looking for solution for my function to work normally. If my function will be 'attached' before the $.post() it will not work, because it will not find the html objects which is being added after $.post().  If I 'attach' the click() function after each $.post(), the function multiplies when it's called

Comment: If I understand, all you want is to prevent your button to be called twice. So you want to load post, accept click only once, then load new post, accept click for the only the new post...?

Comment: @B.Assem Not the click only, because my function has more functions inside of it. I want to load post & function with sub-functions, for the sub-functions to work for the new post. And for the same sub-functions called each time with the post, not to duplicate.

Comment: Your are not just loading HTML, but also JS code including the event handlers? If that is the case, then you must post an exemple of the loaded data, because your pbl is probably due to that loaded JS.

Comment: Depending on your Received code, the solution might more simpler than what you thought

Comment: @B.Assem Mate, my issue is very simple to understand. I am loading my functions everytime ajax's being called, because ajax adds the posts for whose the functions are created. However the functions doesn't work if it's loaded earlier than needed HTML (posts). That's why I have to call it everytime ajax is loaded. However, as the function is the same, it's being loaded multiple time and it gives the results multiple times too. I am looking solution to fix that and for the function to work always and not be loaded multiple times.

Comment: I understand, but can you post your Ajax and the data received? (I need the code to give you a proper answer)

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation; attach event to parent element of dynamically created elements and appended element or `document`; substitute `.siblings()` for `$(this).parent().find()`

See

- [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)
- [Events and Event Delegation](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events)

```
$(document).on("click", ".count", function() {
  $(this).siblings(".sum")
  .html(
    parseInt($(this).siblings(".a").html())
    + parseInt($(this).siblings(".b").html())
  );   
});
```

Alternatively, if you need to call a function before each `$.ajax()` call, use `beforeSend` option [Getting code to run syncronously that resides inside a function called via an AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351971/getting-code-to-run-syncronously-that-resides-inside-a-function-called-via-an-aj/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple proposition based on what you said in the comment (but without posting your full code, I might have missed something). My suggestion is that instead of calling `loadCounter` each time you load a new Div with your Ajax (because of that, the already loaded Div will have multiple click event attached to them) just change your loaded html to this:

```
<div class="post">
 <div class="a">1</div>
 <div class="b">8</div>
 <div class="sum">x</div>
 <div onclick="calculate(this)" id="2" class="count">Count</div>
<div>
```

And add this to your JS:

```
function calculate(me) {
  $(me).siblings('.sum').html(parseInt($(me).siblings(".a").html())+parseInt($(me).siblings(".b").html()));
}
```